# Create VM and deploy application on to Azure VM via Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment

I am new to Ansible Azure modules. What I need is the ability to create VM's(n) and deploy an application on all of them. From what I read online  [azure_rm_virtual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html) machine can be used to create VM(Assuming vnet, subnet and other networking jazz is in place). I am trying to figure out how do I deploy(copy bits and run my app installer) my application onto the newly created VM's? Can my app deployment be part of the VM creation process? If so what are the options? I looked into [other modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ansible/ansible-matrix#introduction-to-azurepreviewmodule) but couldn't find any relevant one's. Didn't find any on the azure documentation too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `azure_rm_deployment` module to create VMs.

Because you know what you are deploying, use `azure_rm_networkinterface_facts` to get the IP address of your VM.

Use `add_host` to create an ad-hoc inventory. This all with:

```
---
- name: Create VM
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
```

Once you have your inventory use:

```
- name: Run updates
  hosts: myazureinventory
  gather_facts: true
```

From here, you can install your software. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The ansible role to deploy a VM is now here: [azure-iaas](https://dev.azure.com/chevron/AnsibleRoles/_git/ansible-role-azure-iaas). I couldn't find one called `azure_rm_deployment` in the ansible repo.